# Facebook Graph API - Get translated location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization, location

Is it possible to get a translated location field of a page via the Facebook API?
For example:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fac.ciencias.ul?fields=location
```

That returns the city in English ("Lisbon").
Even this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fac.ciencias.ul?fields=location&locale=pt_PT
```

(specifying the locale 'portuguese') has no effect.
What I would like is to get "Lisboa" (In Portuguese - pt-PT) instead of "Lisbon" (English).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this cannot be translated. You should have a look at the Facebook Page of this University and click the Info link. At the info page you will see that someone entered the address in English

Regards

Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for helping.
In fact if I go there it says 'Lisbon' but I tried changing my facebook language setting to pt-pt and it displayed 'Lisboa', in the info page.